# Object not visible in render with hair particles enabled(!?)

Tags: rendering, particles, hair, visibility

In Viewport everything is okay and visible like it should. Hair and the body. But when I hit render (in Evee and Cycles both) only the hair is visible and not the body.

While searching for the issue I noticed that when I delete the hair particles through the little minus the body is visible again in my render.

How can I fix this that both appear in my final render? It is probably something in my particle settings(?)

Thank You!

**Image 1** normal render without deleting Hair Particles

**Image 2** deleting Hair Particles with the little minus

**Image 3** render without hair particles (body visible again?!)

[image: Render in Evee]

[image: Removing Particles]

[image: Render without Hair Particles]

Comment: I see, you find solution, but anyway your question is duplicate, next time check this list: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, "Show Emitter" under particle settings was not enabled.